# How to loop over all success test results of a Python unittest runner?

Tags: python, python-unittest

After:

```
import unittest 
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
tests = loader.discover('.')
testRunner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner()
testResult = testRunner.run(tests)
```

I can get a list failures names and messages with:

```
for t in testResult.failures:
    print t[0].id()
    print t[1]
```

How to do the same for the successes?

I expect to be able to do it by overriding something in `TextTestRunner`. What is the easiest way?

Tested on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 7):

elethan put me on the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40613695/895245

This is what I got after using `TextTestRunner(resultclass=` and adding a nice constructor:

```
import unittest
from unittest.runner import TextTestResult

class TextTestResultWithSuccesses(TextTestResult):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TextTestResultWithSuccesses, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.successes = []
    def addSuccess(self, test):
        super(TextTestResultWithSuccesses, self).addSuccess(test)
        self.successes.append(test)

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
tests = loader.discover('.')
testRunner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner(resultclass=TextTestResultWithSuccesses)
testResult = testRunner.run(tests)
for t in testResult.failures:
    print t[0].id()
    print t[1]
print
for t in testResult.errors:
    print t[0].id()
    print t[1]
print
for t in testResult.successes:
    print t.id()
```

Comment: Nice! Yeah, my example was copied from some old code where I customized other things about the test runner, but if all you need to do is override the `resultclass` this makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar in the past. The way I would do this is by first creating a test result class that in inherits from `TestTextResult` with a custom `addSuccess` method which will be called on each test success (`addFailure` is the method where the failing tests get appended to `failures`):

```
from unittest.runner import TextTestResult, TextTestRunner

class MyTestResult(TextTestResult):

    successes = []    # As OP points out, this makes more sense as instance attribute 

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        super(TextTestResult, self).addSuccess(test)
        self.successes.append(test)    # add other info if you want
```

and then make your own custom test runner, adding your custom test result as `resultclass`

```
class MyTestRunner(TextTestRunner):

    resultclass = MyTestResult    
    # If this is your only customization, you can just pass 
    # the test runner class to `TextTestRunner`; see OP's answer
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made some minor improvements to this at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40614410/895245 but you put me on the right track.